# Partitioned view with dedicated "routing" column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, partitioning, view

I have an application (Microsoft Dynamics NAV to be exact) that splits up data for different companies in tables with the exact same structure.

I can not change that behavior, so I built VIEWs that make it easier to handle that data for reporting purposes, like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [ALL COMPANIES$Employee]
AS
SELECT 'Company 1' as Company, * FROM [Company 1$Employee]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company 2' as Company, * FROM [Company 2$Employee]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company 3' as Company, * FROM [Company 3$Employee]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company 4' as Company, * FROM [Company 4$Employee]
```

That works well for the `read` case.

Now I want to also use these views for easier interfacing with other applications, that is, `insert`ing and `update`ing data.

I do know about partitioned views, but this is not exactly the same, as I don't have specific columns with CHECK constraints, but "routing" to the underlying tables would have to be done with only the information of the newly introduced column `Company`.

Is there anything like that? Otherwise, I'm happy about all other proposed solutions that save me from using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach if you can't use a partitioned view is `INSTEAD OF` triggers like the examples below.  Note that the `UPDATE` trigger assumes that one never changes a primary key value after the initial insert.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TRI ALL COMPANIES$Employee] ON
    [ALL COMPANIES$Employee]
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS

INSERT INTO [Company 1$Employee] (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM inserted
WHERE Company = 'Company 1';

INSERT INTO [Company 2$Employee] (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM inserted
WHERE Company = 'Company 2';

INSERT INTO [Company 3$Employee] (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM inserted
WHERE Company = 'Company 3';

INSERT INTO [Company 4$Employee] (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM inserted
WHERE Company = 'Company 4';
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [TRU ALL COMPANIES$Employee] ON
    [ALL COMPANIES$Employee]
    INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS

UPDATE target
SET
      Col2 = inserted.Col2
    , Col3 = inserted.Col3
FROM [Company 1$Employee] AS target
JOIN inserted ON inserted.Col1 = target.Col1
WHERE inserted.Company = 'Company 1';

UPDATE target
SET
      Col2 = inserted.Col2
    , Col3 = inserted.Col3
FROM [Company 2$Employee] AS target
JOIN inserted ON inserted.Col1 = target.Col1
WHERE inserted.Company = 'Company 2';

UPDATE target
SET
      Col2 = inserted.Col2
    , Col3 = inserted.Col3
FROM [Company 3$Employee] AS target
JOIN inserted ON inserted.Col1 = target.Col1
WHERE inserted.Company = 'Company 3';

UPDATE target
SET
      Col2 = inserted.Col2
    , Col3 = inserted.Col3
FROM [Company 4$Employee] AS target
JOIN inserted ON inserted.Col1 = target.Col1
WHERE inserted.Company = 'Company 4';
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [TRD ALL COMPANIES$Employee] ON
    [ALL COMPANIES$Employee]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS

DELETE target
FROM [Company 1$Employee] AS target
JOIN deleted ON deleted.Col1 = target.Col1
WHERE deleted.Company = 'Company 1';

DELETE target
FROM [Company 2$Employee] AS target
JOIN deleted ON deleted.Col1 = target.Col1
WHERE deleted.Company = 'Company 2';

DELETE target
FROM [Company 3$Employee] AS target
JOIN deleted ON deleted.Col1 = target.Col1
WHERE deleted.Company = 'Company 3';

DELETE target
FROM [Company 4$Employee] AS target
JOIN deleted ON deleted.Col1 = target.Col1
WHERE deleted.Company = 'Company 4';
GO
```

Comment: Wow, wouldn't have guessed that triggers on views are possible. That works great for me, even though I don't really like the hard coded column names, because that might break things in the future, but hey... Almost perfect :) Thanks!